# How to sum variables by groups in R

Tags: r, database, dataframe

I have a data frame named "SpatialKey" with three columns. First column contains 5 categories representing population quintile. The second column has 4 kind of data: 0, 400, 800 and 1200. The third column represents population.

For example

| quintile | isocrona | total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 1200 | 1674 |
| 1 | 400 | 1676 |
| 4 | 400 | 1723 |
| 5 | 800 | 1567 |
| 3 | 0 | 1531 |
| 3 | 1200 | 1370 |
| 2 | 1200 | 1925 |
| 1 | 400 | 1916 |
| 5 | 0 | 1776 |
| 2 | 800 | 1896 |
| 3 | 800 | 2143 |
| 5 | 400 | 2098 |
| 4 | 400 | 1496 |
| 1 | 0 | 961 |
| 4 | 800 | 1684 |

I want to clasify the data by quintile and sum the population by the 4 kind of data I have in the second column. For example:

|  | 0 | 400 | 800 | 1200 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 961 | 3592 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 0 | 0 | 1896 | 1925 |
| 3 | 1531 | 0 | 2143 | 1370 |
| 4 | 0 | 3219 | 1684 | 1674 |
| 5 | 1776 | 2098 | 1567 | 0 |

And here is my code.

```
po <- SpatialKey %>%
group_by(quintile, isocrona) %>%
summarise_at(vars(contains("total")), sum)
final_df <- as.data.frame(t(po))
```

But R give me the following table:

|  | V1 | V2 | V3 | V4 | V5 | V6 | V7 | V8 | V9 | V10 | V11 | V12 | V13 | V14 | V15 | V16 | V17 | V18 | V19 | V20 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| quintile | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 5 | 5 | 5 | 5 |
| isocrona | 0 | 400 | 800 | 1200 | 0 | 400 | 800 | 1200 | 0 | 400 | 800 | 1200 | 0 | 400 | 800 | 1200 | 0 | 400 | 800 | 1200 |
| total | 961 | 3592 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1896 | 1925 | 1531 | 0 | 2143 | 1370 | 0 | 3219 | 1684 | 1674 | 1776 | 2098 | 1567 | 0 |

How would I do the second table in R?

Answer (score 2):

Use xtabs.  Put the variable to be summed on the left hand side of the formula and the others on the right hand side.  We can use dot to mean all the rest.  No packages are used.

```
xtabs(total ~., SpatialKey)
```

giving  this xtabs table:

```
        isocrona
quintile    0  400  800 1200
       1  961 3592    0    0
       2    0    0 1896 1925
       3 1531    0 2143 1370
       4    0 3219 1684 1674
       5 1776 2098 1567    0
```

### Note

The input in reproducible form is:

```
SpatialKey <- structure(list(quintile = c(4L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 
2L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 4L), isocrona = c(1200L, 400L, 400L, 800L, 
0L, 1200L, 1200L, 400L, 0L, 800L, 800L, 400L, 400L, 0L, 800L), 
    total = c(1674L, 1676L, 1723L, 1567L, 1531L, 1370L, 1925L, 
    1916L, 1776L, 1896L, 2143L, 2098L, 1496L, 961L, 1684L)), 
    class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -15L))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here we need a `pivot_wider` to reshape into 'wide' format while doing the `sum`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
SpatialKey %>%
    arrange(quintile, isocrona) %>%
    pivot_wider(names_from = isocrona, values_from = total, 
        values_fn = sum, values_fill = 0)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 5 x 5
#  quintile   `0` `400` `800` `1200`
#     <int> <int> <int> <int>  <int>
#1        1   961  3592     0      0
#2        2     0     0  1896   1925
#3        3  1531     0  2143   1370
#4        4     0  3219  1684   1674
#5        5  1776  2098  1567      0
```

---

Or use `xtabs` from `base R`

```
xtabs(total ~ quintile + isocrona, SpatialKey)
```

#### data

```
SpatialKey <- structure(list(quintile = c(4L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 
2L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 4L), isocrona = c(1200L, 400L, 400L, 800L, 
0L, 1200L, 1200L, 400L, 0L, 800L, 800L, 400L, 400L, 0L, 800L), 
    total = c(1674L, 1676L, 1723L, 1567L, 1531L, 1370L, 1925L, 
    1916L, 1776L, 1896L, 2143L, 2098L, 1496L, 961L, 1684L)), 
    class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-15L))
```

Answer (score 1):

A method based on the idea of `group`. The benefit is the result is still the dataframe format.

Result of long format:

```
library(data.table)
dt.long <- setDT(SpatialKey)[,sum(total),keyby = .(quintile,isocrona)]
dt.long

   quintile isocrona   V1
 1:        1        0  961
 2:        1      400 3592
 3:        2      800 1896
 4:        2     1200 1925
 5:        3        0 1531
 6:        3      800 2143
 7:        3     1200 1370
 8:        4      400 3219
 9:        4      800 1684
10:        4     1200 1674
11:        5        0 1776
12:        5      400 2098
13:        5      800 1567
```

Result of wide format:

```
dcast(dt.long,quintile ~ isocrona,fill = 0,value.var = "V1")

   quintile    0  400  800 1200
1:        1  961 3592    0    0
2:        2    0    0 1896 1925
3:        3 1531    0 2143 1370
4:        4    0 3219 1684 1674
5:        5 1776 2098 1567    0
```

Data:

```
SpatialKey <- structure(list(quintile = c(4L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 
2L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 4L), isocrona = c(1200L, 400L, 400L, 800L, 
0L, 1200L, 1200L, 400L, 0L, 800L, 800L, 400L, 400L, 0L, 800L), 
    total = c(1674L, 1676L, 1723L, 1567L, 1531L, 1370L, 1925L, 
    1916L, 1776L, 1896L, 2143L, 2098L, 1496L, 961L, 1684L)), 
    class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-15L))
```